# Basic WPF question: How to add a custom property trigger?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, triggers, expression-blend

I am using Expresion Blend 3 and created a new user control in my project. I want a storyboard to run if a custom property of that user control is triggered like with the ones shown here in the list..

[image]

I learnt you need a dependency property, but my understanding there is limited. Here's the basic code I set up with property "IsAwesome" as an example..

```
Partial Public Class simpleControl
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Public Shared ReadOnly IsAwesomeProperty As DependencyProperty = _
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsAwesome", GetType(Boolean), GetType(simpleControl))

    Public Property IsAwesome() As Boolean
        Get
            Return DirectCast(Me.GetValue(IsAwesomeProperty), Boolean)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me.SetValue(IsAwesomeProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

However, my property doesn't show in that list. What am I missing? Or is my entire approach wrong?
Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Your approach is correct. My VB is rusty at best but translating this to equivalent C# works as expected for me (I see my property in the drop down).

 Can you give me more context. What version of Blend are you using? Where are you trying to add the storyboard? Inside the template? Is this a UserControl or a custom Control?

Comment: I'm using Blend 3, the storyboard is inside the UserControl's template. To be honest, I think my problem is that I'm playing with the styles wrong. How did you get to the list with the custom control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new Wpf project. Added a new UserControl (UserControl1) with a custom dependency property called Foo.

Then I opened Blend and added an instance of UserControl1 to Window1. I right clicked on UserControl1 and said EditTemplate | Edit a Copy.

This created a copy of my user control template in the Window.Resources. From within this new template I went up to the Triggers panel and clicked the button to add a new property trigger.

Right away Blend defaulted to selecting my property in the "Activated When" section.

[alt text http://blog.BradCunningham.net/Images/ForumImages/CustomDPInBlend.png](http://blog.BradCunningham.net/Images/ForumImages/CustomDPInBlend.png)

You can grab my little sample app from here: http://blog.BradCunningham.net/SourceCode/ForumSamples/CustomDPInBlend.zip

Comment: Wow! Much appreciated! I guess I was editing templates from the wrong place then. However, is there a way I could alter controls inside the usercontrol from this? eg making visible a textblock saying "This control is empty" if property .IsEmpty is true.

Comment: Sure, In the screen shot I posted I am inside the ControlTemplate for UserControl1. The Trigger I am setting is activated when Foo = null.

As you can see, Blend is showing me (via the red outline) that Foo = null trigger recording is on. This means any properties I change on my visual elements will only be set when the trriger is activated (when Foo = null). If you flip back to Default (i.e. Deactive the Foo = null trigger) you will notice the properties you set inside the Foo trigger are undone.

Comment: But I still can't edit controls inside the UserControl via template editing can I? http://i49.tinypic.com/10wo5q9.png - since they're not available in the Objects list. I guess that can just be done by code then. Thanks, again.